# How to deploy a container on remote machine over ssh using azure pipeline

Tags: docker, ssh, azure-pipelines, exit

I am trying to build my application as container image on Agent and then in deployment step I am doing ssh to target machine and running docker pull/run command to start the container. It's successfully getting up as well, but after sometime container is getting exited.

My doubt is that's it's running in ssh session only and as soon as session is over, container is going down.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - refs/tags/*
      - feature*

pool: Agent_pool

variables:
  - group: azure-creds
  - name: APP_VERSION
    value: $(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(Build.BuildNumber)
  - name: APPLICATION_NAME
    value: myapp
  - name: JAVA_HOME
    value: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  - name: DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY
    value: docker.rtp.orgcloud.com

stages:
  - stage: buildAndTest
    displayName: Building and testing
    jobs:
      - job: buildAndTestJob
        displayName: Building and testing job
        steps:
          - script: |
              export DOCKER_IMAGE="$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY)/$(APPLICATION_NAME):$(APP_VERSION)"
              docker build --build-arg VERSION=$(APP_VERSION) . -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE"
            displayName: Containerize application
          - script: |
              export DOCKER_IMAGE="$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY)/$(APPLICATION_NAME):$(APP_VERSION)"
              docker login -u $(azure_username) -p $(azure_password) $(DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY)
              docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE"
            displayName: Push Container Image to Azure Container Registry
  
  - stage: Deploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature')))
    jobs:
      - job: 'RunDeploymentCommandJob'
        displayName: Deploying job
        steps:
          - task: SSH@0
            env:
              ENVIRONMENT: 'ppe'
            inputs:
              sshEndpoint: 'fuelVM'  # The name of the SSH service connection you created
              runOptions: 'inline'
              inline: |
                echo "started executing commands"
                echo "Before Docker image is set to:$DOCKER_IMAGE"
                export DOCKER_IMAGE="$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY)/$(APPLICATION_NAME):$(APP_VERSION)"
                echo "After Docker image is set to:$DOCKER_IMAGE"
                docker login -u $(azure_username) -p $(azure_password) $(DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY)
                echo "login succeeded"
                echo "Docker image is set to:$DOCKER_IMAGE"
                docker pull $DOCKER_IMAGE
                echo "docker pull completed"
                PREVIOUS_CONTAINER=$(docker ps -aq --filter "name=$APPLICATION_NAME")

                if [ ! -z "$PREVIOUS_CONTAINER" ]; then
                  docker stop "$PREVIOUS_CONTAINER" || true
                  docker rm "$PREVIOUS_CONTAINER" || true
                  echo "stopped previous container"
                fi
                echo "image downloaded, now running containers"
                docker run -d --name $(APPLICATION_NAME) -p 5000:5000 "$DOCKER_IMAGE"
            displayName: 'Deploy to Server'
```

Container logs is as follows:

```
[2023-10-05 07:13:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-05 07:13:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2023-10-05 07:13:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-10-05 07:13:41 +0000] [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
[2023-10-05 08:00:46 +0000] [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
[2023-10-05 08:00:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2023-10-05 08:00:46 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:5) was sent SIGTERM!
[2023-10-05 08:00:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Any suggestion if I am missing anything or better way to achieve it ?

Thanks,

Comment: A better way to achieve this is to use a service like Container Apps to run your container instead of maintaining an entire virtual machine.

Comment: what's the type of your pipeline agent? Microsoft hosted agent, VMSS or Self-hosted agent?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT self hosted agent

Comment: @DanielMann target vm is not in azure, it's in my organization's private cloud. There's no container apps.